# jquery wrap function not working

Tags: jquery

my html is like this

```
    <div id="149708366" class="fav-list">
      <em style="display:none">&nbsp;</em>
    </div>
```

and my jquery code to wrap this with a new div( $(data) reffers to above html)

```
 alert( $(data).find(list).wrap('<div class="new" />').html());
```

and I am expecting below html as result

```
   <div id="149708366" class="fav-list">
      <em style="display:none">&nbsp;</em>
    </div>
```

but only gets this in jquery alert message

```
<em style="display:none">&nbsp;</em>
```

can any one help me on this.

Comment: Problem is `$(data).find(list).wrap(...)` returns the same as `$(data).find(list)`. In other words, `.wrap()` returns what is wrapped, not the wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

```
alert( $(data).find(list).wrap('<div class="new" />').parent().html());
```

Answer (score 1):

`wrap()` returns the original element, thus the output is correct.

> This method returns the original set of elements for chaining
>   purposes.

Comment: yes from my understanding now the inner contet is my expected result as i had wrapped it with a new div

Comment: @AKS What do data and list refer to?

Comment: @AKS In order to verify that the function did in fact work, use the DOM explorer.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to find out the details behind this